# Use of unresolved identifier 'PHPhotoLibrary'

Tags: swift, macos, xcode7, photos

I am working on a Photos extension for Mac OS X (10.11).

I have the Photos and PhotosUI frameworks imported.

Everything is ok apart from when I try to make a call to PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().

This results in an error in Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014):

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'PHPhotoLibrary'
```

Has anyone else experienced this or know what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes—this API doesn't exist on OS X.

Comment: Really? Well that would explain the issue. I'm looking to save an asset and thought it was necessary to call the library for a change request. Will need to read more then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* the `PHPhotoLibrary` class to make a photo editing extension in either iOS or OS X, and in OS X you *can't* use it.

The entire workflow for a photo editing extension goes through the [`PHContentEditingController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHContentEditingController_Protocol/) protocol. On both platforms, the main view controller of a photo editing extension implements this protocol. It provides the asset to be edited in the [`startContentEditingWithInput:placeholderImage:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHContentEditingController_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/PHContentEditingController/startContentEditingWithInput:placeholderImage:) method, and when the user is done editing it calls your [`finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHContentEditingController_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/PHContentEditingController/finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler:) method so you can apply your final-quality edits and provide output.

Notice I say "when the user is done editing". Saving to the photo library isn't something you do in your extension code — instead Photos asks you for final rendered output, and Photos handles saving it to the library.

In your [`finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHContentEditingController_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/PHContentEditingController/finishContentEditingWithCompletionHandler:) method, you should:

1. Create a `PHContentEditingOutput` from the `PHContentEditingInput` (which you received in `startContentEditingWithInput:placeholderImage:`).
2. Save your output as a JPEG file (or QuickTime movie file, for video assets) to the `renderedContentURL` that the PHContentEditingOutput specifies
3. Call the `completionHandler` block that was passed to you, passing it your `PHContentEditingOutput`.

You calling that completion handler is what triggers Photos saving the edited asset to the library.

Comment: Rickster thank you very much for replying to my post. I have exactly that but am getting errors when saving to the renderedContentUrl - Xcode says the file already exists. I thought the error may have been related to the PHPhoto library needing to give permission to the extension to save the file.

Comment: No permission issue: the user has implicitly given your extension permission to write the edited asset because they chose your extension to edit that asset. Sometimes you need to delete what's at the renderedContentURL before you can write it.

Comment: If I can't use PHPhotoLibrary on macOS, what other API exists to access Photos on Mac?

Comment: As noted, you don't need `PHPhotoLibrary` to make a photo editing extension, which was the subject of this question. (If you're looking for other purposes, it's clearer to ask a separate question.)